# Sobolev space and integration by parts on non-orientable manifolds

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact manifold without boundary which is not orientable. Do all the standard facts that apply to oriented manifolds and Sobolev spaces also apply here? Like Green's formula for example.

In Hebey's books on this subject, he never says that the manifold is orientable, but this may be an implicit assumption because it seems that he uses the volume form on the manifold and doesn't say anything about densities...

Comment: Wouldn't the validity of Green's formula follow from Strong Whitney on a closed manifold?

Comment: @Bacon I think you're right that it holds. I am wondering what actually fails in this case.

Comment: It seems like you could get back a lot of the theory by working with a subclass of functions on the orientation double cover (smooth functions that respect the nontrivial deck transformation ie $f(x)=f(\iota(x))$). Then putting the standard Sobolev norms (now possible because we can integrate!) and completing with respect to these should give you the standard Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements like Green's theorem are identities that are linear in the function(s) involved. This allows us to localize their consideration: cover $M$ by coordinate patches (open subsets diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$). Let $\{\varphi_k\}$ be a smooth partition of unity subordinate to this cover. Sine $u=\sum_k u\varphi_k$, you apply the identity to $u \varphi_k$ (which holds since there are no issues with orientability locally), and add the results.